# Why is my subscript out of range in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I wanted excel to go through every single cell of a column, perform an operation on it and then copy the results on another column. 
This was my initial code:

```
For i = 2 To dataRows
    '    Cells(i, aStampCol) = Cells(i, stampCol) - stim1TimeStamp 
    'Next i
```

This code actually worked, but ran extremely slowly, I looked at another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555451/why-is-my-loop-so-slow) and they were saying it was better to just copy the column into an array, manipulate it and then copy it back to a column.

So I wrote the following code:

```
cellsAStamp = Range(Cells(2, stampCol), Cells(datarows, stampCol)) 
For i = 0 To datarows - 2
    cellsAStamp(i) = cellsAStamp(i) - stim1TimeStamp
Next i

Range(Cells(2, aStampCol), Cells(endRow, aStampCol)) = cellsAStamp
```

The problem is, as soon as the for loop is initiated, I get a "Subscript out of Range" error. I get the impression that the cellsAsStamp is not storing the data properly, but I don't exactly know how to solve this problem, or for that matter, what the problem is!

I've pasted my full code below so you can look at how I initialized the variables:

```
Sub WM()
Dim col As Integer
Dim spanCol As Integer
Dim msgCol As Integer
Dim stampCol As Integer   'The column containing the timestamp
Dim aStampCol As Integer 'The column containing the adjusted timestamp
Dim row As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim stimRow As Long 'the row on the Sample_Message column that says "stim1"
Dim endRow As Long  'the row on the Sample_Message column that says "participant_trial_end"
Dim triNum() As String 'a string array that will hold "Trial: x" after it has been split
Dim stim1TimeStamp As Long
Dim cellsAStamp() As Variant 'will contain the names of all the NoBlink sheets to allow for

'Identifies Timestamp column, adds ADJUSTED_TIMESTAMP column
For stampCol = 1 To 10
    If Cells(1, stampCol) = "TIMESTAMP" Then
            aStampCol = stampCol
            colLetter = ConvertToLetter(stampCol)
            Columns(colLetter & ":" & colLetter).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            stampCol = stampCol + 1
            Cells(1, aStampCol) = "ADJUSTED_TIMESTAMP"
        GoTo out
    End If
Next stampCol

out:

'Identifies Trial Label column
For col = 1 To 10
    If Cells(1, col) = "TRIAL_LABEL" Then
        GoTo out1
    End If
Next col

out1:

'Identifies Span column
For spanCol = 1 To 10
    If Cells(1, spanCol) = "span" Then
        GoTo out2
    End If
Next spanCol

out2:

'Identifies Message column
For msgCol = 1 To 10
    If Cells(1, msgCol) = "SAMPLE_MESSAGE" Then
        GoTo out3
    End If
Next msgCol

out3:

'Goes through Trial_Label column and deletes trials 1 and 2
row = 2
While Cells(row, col) Like "Trial: [12]"
    row = row + 1
 Wend
 row = row - 1

    If row = 1 Then 'in case the trials weren't there, it wont start at the header
        row = 2
        GoTo skipDelete
    End If

 Rows("2:" & CStr(row)).Delete

skipDelete:

'Goes through Trial_Label column and stops once the trial changes
row = 2
GoTo stillMoreLeft
stillMoreLeft:
 startRow = row
 currTrial = Cells(row, col) 'did not initialize currSpan and currTrial as strings
 currSpan = Cells(row, spanCol)

    While currTrial = Cells(row, col)
        'highlights any row that has a message
        If Cells(row, msgCol) <> "." Then
            Rows(CStr(row) & ":" & CStr(row)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If

        'Identifies the row that contains "stim1" in Sample_Message
        If Cells(row, msgCol) = "stim1" Then
            stimRow = row
        End If

        'Identifies the row that contains "participant_trial_end" in Sample_Message
        If Cells(row, msgCol) = "participant_trial_end" Then
            endRow = row
        End If

        row = row + 1
    Wend
    row = row - 1
'Copies all of the rows containted in a trial
Rows(CStr(stimRow) & ":" & CStr(endRow)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Creates new sheet that will be named appropriately
Worksheets.Add
triNum = Split(currTrial)
currSheetName = "Trial" & triNum(1) & "Span" & currSpan
ActiveSheet.Name = currSheetName

'Pastes all the rows contained in at trial
Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Gets timestamp for stim1
stim1TimeStamp = Cells(2, stampCol)

'Puts the whole timestamp column in an array/ Does the appropriate calculations to each value
datarows = endRow - stimRow + 2
cellsAStamp = Range(Cells(2, stampCol), Cells(datarows, stampCol)) 'looks like a legit way to use range
For i = 0 To datarows - 2
    cellsAStamp(i) = cellsAStamp(i) - stim1TimeStamp
Next i

Range(Cells(2, aStampCol), Cells(endRow, aStampCol)) = cellsAStamp

'Fills the Adjusted_TimeStamp column
'dataRows = endRow - stimRow + 2
'For i = 2 To dataRows
'    Cells(i, aStampCol) = Cells(i, stampCol) - stim1TimeStamp 'This equation says: the Adjusted_Time_Stamp=TimeStamp-TimeStamp of Stim1
'Next i

'Copies header row and pastes it to first row of most recent trial sheet
Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(currSheetName).Select
Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

row = row + 1 'we increment the row so that on the next line, when they check for whether the cell is empty or not, we aren't looking at the last cell of our current trial, but the first cell of our following trial
Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Select

'Looks to see if there is still a trial left, if so, it goes through all of it
If Cells(row, col) <> "" Then
    GoTo stillMoreLeft
Else
    bob = 1 + 1
End If

End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
Dim iAlpha As Integer
Dim iRemainder As Integer
iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
If iAlpha > 0 Then
  ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
End If
If iRemainder > 0 Then
  ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a range into an array, it will be a 2D array (1-based) -- dimension one is the rows, dimension two is the columns -- even if there is just one column.  So try:

```
cellsAStamp(i,1) = cellsAStamp(i,1) - stim1TimeStamp
```