# VBA Faster Data Clean Up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a Sub to help clean up a large data set I need to work with each week. the data is a list of products, with a total and size for each, so it looks something like this:

Product 1 All

Product 1 Small

Product 1 Medium

Product 2 All

I only want to keep a product if it matches one of 3 criteria, but if it does I want to keep all rows for that product. If a product doesn't match any of the 3 criteria, I want to delete every row that has that product.

I've written the below code, which does seem to be working, but takes ages.

```
For i = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
If Data.Range("F" & i) = "All" Then

    TY_Sales = Data.Range("K" & i)
    LY_Sales = Data.Range("L" & i)
    TY_Stock = Data.Range("O" & i)
    Sales_Stock = TY_Sales + LY_Sales + TY_Stock

    If Sales_Stock <= 0 Then
    vendor_ref = Data.Range("E" & i)
        For j = i + 10 To i Step -1
            If Data.Range("E" & j) = vendor_ref Then
            Data.Range("E" & j).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
Next
```

Its taking ages because my original data set is 17k rows, and I know I'm iterating through it all over and over again, but I don't know a better way to do it more quickly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume cell "F" & i is part of the data dump, and identifies that the row you're on is something like a line-item? Or is that cell something where you have a manual formula that checks whether all categories are met, and then puts in "All"?

Comment: column F is the column that lists the size of the product, and All is a row for each product that contains data for the entire product. It those rows that I'm interesting in meeting my criteria, thats why I've included that

Comment: You routine is slow because you're trying to walk through each cell in the range.  What you want to do is range-array copying, explained here, along with other performance tips: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19167804/109122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general advice would be to create a dictionary, which is an Array of values that can be accessed with either an ordered index number or a name key. With that dictionary, first go through all rows of data. Look column E: does the name in "E" & i exist yet in the dictionary? If not, add it to the dictionary. Then take the dictionary ID (either newly created, or which was created on a previous row), and add that row with columns K, L, and O to the value of the dictionary's entry.

Then, once you have all the names collected with the dictionary, and you have added up columns K, L, and O, go back through all rows (from bottom-up). For the index ID of that row, is the value from the dictionary entry >0? If yes, delete that row.

But to complicate things, you need to add a separate (free, microsoft supported) scripting package to use Dictionaries. So instead, we will make our own. The only thing this means is that each time a new row is checked for a unique name, we need to cycle through the list of unique names thus-far, and check each one individually, instead of using that name as an index. See my revised code below, with comments on changes made from yours. Note that I set all variables at the beginning, including declaring Data to be = sheets(1), which may differ from your sub.

```
Sub Delete_Unnecessary_Rows()

Dim i As Integer
Dim TY_Sales As Long, LY_Sales As Long, TY_Stock As Long, Sales_Stock As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim vendor_ref As String

Dim VendorStringArray() As String 'This Array will hold all unique vendor names
Dim VendorNumArray() As Long 'This array will hold the Sales Stock value for each unique vendor name
Dim VendorRowIdentifier() As Long 'For each row, this will hold the index for particular unique vendor name
Dim UniqueNameCounter As Long 'This will hold the number of confirmed unique names

Dim UniqueCheck As Boolean


Set data = Sheets(1)

LastRow = data.Cells(data.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim VendorStringArray(3 To LastRow) 'resize the array to be the full possible amount of unique string values
ReDim VendorNumArray(3 To LastRow)
ReDim VendorRowIdentifier(3 To LastRow)

For i = 3 To LastRow 'new loop to find new dictionary names
    If data.Range("F" & i) = "All" Then 'This is a data row to be searched for a unique vendor name

        UniqueCheck = True 'Holds TRUE until a duplicate value is found in a higher row

        vendor_ref = data.Range("E" & i).Formula 'Grabs the vendor name and Sales_Stock amount for that row
        TY_Sales = data.Range("K" & i)
        LY_Sales = data.Range("L" & i)
        TY_Stock = data.Range("O" & i)
        Sales_Stock = TY_Sales + LY_Sales + TY_Stock
        If UniqueNameCounter > 0 Then 'If there's already been at least 1 unique name, check prior unique names to try and find a match

            For j = UniqueNameCounter To 1 Step -1 'works backwards through prior unique counters to find a match
                If vendor_ref = VendorStringArray(j + 2) Then
                    UniqueCheck = False 'A match has been found
                    VendorRowIdentifier(i) = j + 2 'associates the row being searched with the index of the unique vendor name for the matched row
                    VendorNumArray(VendorRowIdentifier(i)) = VendorNumArray(VendorRowIdentifier(i)) + Sales_Stock 'adds the new sales stock value to the old one with that unique vendor name
                    j = 0 'stops the formula from looping after a match is found

                End If
            Next j
        End If
        If UniqueCheck Then 'no match was found for that name in an above row
                UniqueNameCounter = UniqueNameCounter + 1
                VendorStringArray(UniqueNameCounter + 2) = vendor_ref 'adds the text to be matched against future values in the array, starting at 3 instead of 1
                VendorRowIdentifier(i) = UniqueNameCounter + 2 'associates the row being searched with the index of the unique vendor name
                VendorNumArray(UniqueNameCounter + 2) = Sales_Stock
        End If
    End If

Next i


For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1 'After determining which rows have values, delete all such rows
    If data.Range("F" & i) = "All" Then
        If VendorNumArray(VendorRowIdentifier(i)) > 0 Then 'Pull the value of the unique vendor name associated with that row #'s vendor and check the size associated
            data.Rows(i).Delete 'Delete the row if any value has been assigned to that vendor
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

As suggested by Dr. Trey, you can also eliminate auto-updating etc. during the processing, to further save time in operation.

Comment: Cheers, this works well. I haven't dealt with something like this before, so took a second to get my head around it, but I like the logic.
 I'll test the sumifs answer on my data tomorrow as well, but this processed everything reasonably quick, which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method. Instead of manually looping and checking for values in matching vendor names, this method uses the native Excel SUMIFS function on each line, to see if any matching rows have values. Each row is then assigned either TRUE or FALSE through an Array of Boolean values. Then the loop is performed again and the rows marked TRUE are deleted. This method only loops through all rows 2x, although using SUMIFS may be more intensive than the manual loop above. However I believe this method is easier to understand.

Disclosure: I have tested both methods and confirmed they work, but not sure on what the difference in processing time will be.

```
Sub CheckDelete_WithSumifs()

Dim i As Integer
Dim TY_Sales As Long, LY_Sales As Long, TY_Stock As Long, Sales_Stock As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim Vendor_Ref As String
Dim DeleteRowCheck() As Boolean

Set data = Sheets(1)

LastRow = data.Cells(data.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim DeleteRowCheck(3 To LastRow) 'resize the array to be the full possible amount of unique string values

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1  'new loop to find new dictionary names
    If data.Range("F" & i) = "All" Then 'Only check to delete if the word All is in column F

        Vendor_Ref = data.Range("E" & i).Formula 'Grabs the vendor name and Sales_Stock amount for that row
        TY_Sales = GrabSumifs(data.Range("K:K"), Vendor_Ref, data) ' See function below
        LY_Sales = GrabSumifs(data.Range("L:L"), Vendor_Ref, data)
        TY_Stock = GrabSumifs(data.Range("O:O"), Vendor_Ref, data)

        Sales_Stock = TY_Sales + LY_Sales + TY_Stock 'Total value of all columns K, L, O for that vendor name

        If Sales_Stock > 0 Then
            DeleteRowCheck(i) = True 'Used in the loop below to define whether to delete the row
        Else
            DeleteRowCheck(i) = False
        End If
    End If

Next i

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1 'After determining which rows have are marked TRUE to delete, delete those rows
    If DeleteRowCheck(i) Then
        data.Rows(i).Delete 'Delete the row if any value has been assigned to that vendor
    End If
Next


End Sub

Function GrabSumifs(SumRange, Vendor_Ref, data) As Long

'This function uses the SUMIFS formula native to Excel, to check the given column to see if any values are present with an identicial vendor name & "All" in column F.
GrabSumifs = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumRange, data.Range("F:F"), "All", data.Range("E:E"), Vendor_Ref)

End Function
```