# VBA performing array formula to index and match results

Tags: arrays, vba, indexing, match

First off all it's my first post on this forum, hello everyone!

I was wondering if anyone knows how to speed up below code? Basically it tends to go Out of resource error if spreadsheet I am importing into this one is too big.

I am running array calculations across 9 columns with different variables. 
Index is running through a spreadhseet of roughly 20k rows with more than 1 variables in it. I bet that instead of running array I could achieve same with for each loop question is, it would have to deeply nested wouldn't it? Would that be faster than array?

Also, is defining names speeding up or slowing down excel?

Please see code below.

```
Sub Recalculate()
'
' Recalculate Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    'Clear content
    Range("C5:AP54").ClearContents
    Range("C5:AP54").ClearComments

    'C5 - Reactive Actions
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-2]:C[8],SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C[11]=""Reactive"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C[-2]),IF((Sheet1!C[53]=""Open Actions""),ROW(Sheet1!C[-2])-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C[-2]))+1,"""")),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[3])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5:C54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C5:C54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'D5
    Range("D5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[2], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[7],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D5:D54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D5:D54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'E6
    Range("E5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[4], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[6],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E5:E54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E5:E54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'F6
    Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[60], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[5],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F5:F54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F5:F54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'G5
    Range("G5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:G54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'H5 - Planned Actions
    Range("H5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C11,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C14=""Extra Works"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),IF((Sheet1!C56=""Open Actions""),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,"""")),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-1])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H5:H54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H5:H54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'I5
    Range("I5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-3], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[2],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I5:I54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("I5:I54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'J5
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-1], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[1],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J5:J54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("J5:J54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'K5
    Range("K5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[55], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C,0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K5:K54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("K5:K54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'L5
    Range("L5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L5:L54"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'M5 - Extra Works Actions
    Range("M5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C11,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C14=""Planned"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),IF((Sheet1!C56=""Open Actions""),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,"""")),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-6])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M5:M54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M5:M54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'N5
    Range("N5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-8], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-3],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N5:N54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("N5:N54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'O5
    Range("O5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-6], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-4],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O5:O54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("O5:O54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'P5
    Range("P5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[50], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[-5],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P5:P53"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("P5:P54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Q5
    Range("Q5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q5:Q54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'R5 - Ambers
    Range("R5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C60,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C60=""Amber"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),IF(NOT(Sheet1!C[-4]=""Planned""),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,"""")),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-11])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R5:R54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("R5:R54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'S5
    Range("S5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-13], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-8],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S5:S54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("S5:S54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'T5
    Range("T5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-11], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-9],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T5:T54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("T5:T54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'U5
    Range("U5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[13], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[-10],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("U5:U54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("U5:U54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'V5
    Range("V5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("V5:V54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'W5 - 3 Day Ambers
    Range("W5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C60,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C60=""3 Day Ambers"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),IF(NOT(Sheet1!C[-9]=""Planned""),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,"""")),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-16])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("W5:W54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("W5:W54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'X5
    Range("X5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-18], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-13],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("X5:X54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("X5:X54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Y5
    Range("Y5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-16], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-14],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y5:Y54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("Y5:Y54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Z5
    Range("Z5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[8], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[-15],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z5:Z54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("Z5:Z54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AA5
    Range("AA5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA5:AA54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AB5 - Red
    Range("AB5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C60,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C60=""Red"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,""""),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-21])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB5:AB54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AB5:AB54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AC5
    Range("AC5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-23], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-18],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC5:AC54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AC5:AC54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AD5
    Range("AD5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-21], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-19],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD5:AD54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AD5:AD54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'AE5
    Range("AE5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[3], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[-20],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE5:AE54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AE5:AE54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AF5
    Range("AF5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF5:AF54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AK5 - Freebar
    Range("AK5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C60,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C33=""FREE"",IF((Area=Sheet1!C1),ROW(Sheet1!C1)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C1))+1,""""),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-30])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AK5:AK54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AK5:AK54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AL5
    Range("AL5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-32], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-27],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AL5:AL54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AM5
    Range("AM5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-30], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-28],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AM5:AM54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AO5
    Range("AO5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AO5:AO54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AP5 - STAT PPM
    Range("AP5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-41]:C[-31],SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C[-41]=Area,IF(Sheet1!C[-28]=""Planned"",IF((Sheet1!C[-27]=""Statutory""),IF((Sheet1!C[10]<Next),IF((Sheet1!C[10]>Last),ROW(Sheet1!C[-41])-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C[-41]))+1,"""")))),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-35])),11),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AP5:AP54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AP5:AP54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AQ5
    Range("AQ5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-37], MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-32],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AQ5:AQ54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AQ5:AQ54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AR5
    Range("AR5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-35], MATCH(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-33],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AR5:AR54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AR5:AR54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AS5
    Range("AS5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-11], MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!C[-34],0)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS5:AS54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AS5:AS54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'AT5
    Range("AT5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AT5:AT54"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'borders
    Range("C5:F54, H5:K54, M5:P54, R5:U54, W5:Z54, AB5:AE54, AG5:AI54, AK5:AN54, AP5:AS54").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    'end
    Rows("5:54").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 12
    Range("F5").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "All ok."

End Sub
```

Comment: If it helps please see most complicated array that's being performed in AO column:
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:K,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!A:A=Area,IF(Sheet1!N:N="Planned",IF((Sheet1!O:O="Statutory"),IF((Sheet1!AZ:AZ<Next),IF((Sheet1!AZ:AZ>Last),ROW(Sheet1!A:A)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!A:A))+1,"")))),""),ROW(G1)),11),"")}

Reason why macro is that I cannot set it to manual calculation as I am working on various spreadsheet at the same time and some of them must be automatic.

Comment: Please see this answer here for Excel VBA performance rules.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167804/109122

Comment: Also, "performance" and "Out of resource" errors are two different things.  Which is it?  If it is the latter, then you need to tell us which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Adding names impact performance one way or another for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, errors are usually happening here:

        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C[-41]:C[-31],SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C[-41]=Area,IF(Sheet1!C[-28]=""Planned"",IF((Sheet1!C[-27]=""Statutory""),IF((Sheet1!C[10]<Next),IF((Sheet1!C[10]>Last),ROW(Sheet1!C[-41])-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!C[-41]))+1,"""")))),""""),ROW(R[-4]C[-35])),11),"""")"


It's Out of resource error, don't worry about performance im quite happy even though its slow, as long as it doesn't exhaust all ram. I have submitted formula which is being run in that part of code in previous comment

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it's not giving me that error on each occasion. It depends on computer I run it on and what am I  performing in background like other spreadsheets