# Simple loop but through 50 000+ lines

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, line

I have few reports to create everyday, based on a DB of more than 1 500 000 Lines....
2 of my modules are really slow, and I suppose this come from a loop I added for 50 000 lines.

I do simple VBA since years, however I don't know how I could speed it up.
Any chances you can help with this?
Please

```
MasterLastRow = WS_Mast_QCF.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Set LibDisc = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_Disc").Range("A2:C100")
Set LibSS = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_SS").Range("D2:G10000")
Set LibMod = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_Mod").Range("B2:G1000")

      
For n = 2 To MasterLastRow
On Error Resume Next
    
    Modu = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("B" & n).Value
    SS = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("E" & n).Value
    Disc = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("G" & n).Value
    QCFStatus = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("N" & n).Value

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("A" & n) = .VLookup(Modu, LibMod, 6, False)
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("C" & n) = .VLookup(SS, LibSS, 3, False)
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("D" & n) = .VLookup(SS, LibSS, 4, False)
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("F" & n) = .VLookup(SS, LibSS, 2, False)
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("G" & n) = .VLookup(Disc, LibDisc, 3, False)
    End With
    
    If SS = "" Then
        WS_Mast_QCF.Range("C" & n & ":F" & n) = "TBD"
    End If

    ' QCF Status Treatment
        Select Case QCFStatus
            Case Is = "Inspection Step", "Open RFI"
                WS_Mast_QCF.Range("H" & n).Value = "Pending"
                WS_Mast_QCF.Range("N" & n).Value = ""
            Case Is <> "Inspection Step", "Open RFI"
                WS_Mast_QCF.Range("H" & n).Value = "Done"
        End Select
Next n
```

Comment: You indicate this is VBA so please add the VBA tag. Also, it looks like you are building an Excel spreadsheet so please add an Excel spreadsheet. Is `WS_Mast_QCF` the direct source of your input data or can you access the DB directly?

Comment: Generally the best way to optimize code like this that is going to be run 50,000 times is to take somethings out of the loop.  But we cannot do that because you haven't shown us the loop(s) nor how this code is used within them.

Comment: @DanielDearlove I've added the tags

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.  I don't know what you mean by "VBA tag". The WS_Mast_QCF is a Worksheet based on a SQL query (.obdc)

Comment: @RBarryYoung. You can see the loop For.. Next .

Comment: @nikau  My apologies, you are correct.

Comment: @DanielDearlove, Don't know how to add the spreasheet. And yes, this is a simple spreadsheet.

Comment: I guess the `LibDisc` is a range? You could, which theoretically should be way faster, store all ranges and fields as arrays and then perform Vlookup (My guess is that the vlookup takes som time to execute). Is more coding and quite a lot of work, but then you won't read from the spreadsheet which you do now. Calculations will be performed solely in the memory. A simple example: [vba-array-vlookup](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?55832-vlookup-array-values)

Comment: If you can access the data directly via a SQL query then I expect you can improve the performance. Also, it looks like you are directly accessing multiple spreadsheet cells per loop and that is most likely very slow. If you can read a whole row at a time or you can write whole columns at a time then you can probably improve the performance too. Are any of these options feasible?

Comment: @Wizhi Yes LibDisc is a range. This is what I thought, UnfortunateIy know NOTHING about arrays.... I will chek your example

Comment: Can you put the actual performance you are getting into your question, such as "processing 50,000 lines in 30 seconds". Also, what performance level are you looking for? Have you done any other benchmarking?

Comment: Once you have some benchmarking information, you can check if iterating over the [rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.rows#example) then accessing the column from the current-row object is faster.

Comment: @DanielDearlove I did some benchmark. the average is 50 000 lines in 1 minutes. I have other macros and worksheets also to run to do 1 report. Knowing that the db is in France and i'm in Russia.  And I have 47 of them to do.  So 47x2minutes  is more than 1 hour. I need to improve all that. The arrays solution seems good given by wizhi, I will give it a try.

Comment: @nikau, thanks for the information. Processing 47 similar reports makes the scale of your problem different from "a few reports". So it looks like a 2-step process, the first is creating a subset of the whole database and putting the results into the `WS_Mast_QCF` spreadsheet and the second step is the loop, above. Is that correct? Do you have a script that executes this whole process end-to-end?

Comment: In fact this is more than that. I have something like (47x2) sql queries (not all open in the same time). For the 47, I create WS_Mast_QCF and WSM_Mast_PL,. From those I create 3 more summary Worksheets and add data to a 4th one, an overall page. After that I have to open 47 other workbooks coming from around the world, take data from them, update my biggest report that covers the 47 blocks. And yes I do all in 1 run. And I save "intermediate" detailled reports (xls and pdf) for the 47 blocks. Also I will have more data to come from other files/dbs.  FYI, I've learnt VBA by myself, on the job.

Comment: @nikau, to generate so many reports from such a large dataset is pretty impressive when you are completely self-taught. I am glad to see that you have completely automated the generation of the reports. Respect.

Comment: @nikau, I asked the questions in my last post because I want to understand the end-to-end process. There are probably some optimizations you can achieve in your scripts. However, I believe you will get better performance in the long run by using a different toolset but I know nothing about the tools at your workplace. You want to minimize clock time to generate the final report so maybe you can do that by learning VB.NET with Excel Interop, breaking the process into chunks and use Jenkins for scheduling. But that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing in Excel-VBA there are several rules that you should follow for best performance as I have outlined in this previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167804/109122).  To summarize it, minimize your VBA's interactions with the Excel model/spreadsheet, primarily by using Range-Array copying instead of reading and writing individual cells and/or ranges.

Additionally, as I mentioned in my comment above, generally the way that you optimize loops is to find ways to move work outside of the loop.

Combining these two I have derived the code below as one way to do this.  Without your data/spreadsheet I cannot test it, but it should be pretty close to working correctly and it will be many times faster.  Note that this code is significantly longer primarily because I have include the `Dim` statements and because I have retained some of the intermediate steps  (like the Lib* variables) to make it easier to see how it relates to the original code.

```
MasterLastRow = WS_Mast_QCF.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Set LibDisc = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_Disc").Range("A2:C100")
Set LibSS = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_SS").Range("D2:G10000")
Set LibMod = WB_Master.Worksheets("Lib_Mod").Range("B2:G1000")

' Copy the lookup ranges values into arrays
Dim DiscA() As Variant, SSA() As Variant, ModA() As Variant
DiscA = LibDisc.Value
SSA = LibSS.Value
ModA = LibMod.Value

' Make dictionaries of VLookup indexes
Dim VlookupMod As Scripting.Dictionary 'note: must add "Microsoft Sripting Runtime" in Add Tools References
Dim VlookupSS As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim VlookupDisc As Scripting.Dictionary
Set VlookupDisc = BuildVLookupDictionary(DiscA)
Set VlookupMod = BuildVLookupDictionary(ModA)
Set VlookupSS = BuildVLookupDictionary(SSA)

' Copy the read/writeable area into two arrays
Dim QcfA() As Variant, QCFStatusA() As Variant
QcfA = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("A1:H50000").Value
QCFStatusA = WS_Mast_QCF.Range("N1:N50000").Value

' Define some convenient column indexes
Const Ax = 1: Const Bx = 2: Const Cx = 3: Const Dx = 4: Const Ex = 5
Const Fx = 6: Const Gx = 7: Const Hx = 8

' loop through every row
For n = 2 To MasterLastRow
On Error Resume Next
    
    Modu = QcfA(n, Bx)
    SS = QcfA(n, Ex)
    Disc = QcfA(n, Gx)
    QCFStatus = QCFStatusA(n, 1)

    QcfA(n, Ax) = ModA(VlookupMod(Modu), 6)
    QcfA(n, Cx) = SSA(VlookupSS(SS), 3)
    QcfA(n, Dx) = SSA(VlookupSS(SS), 4)
    QcfA(n, Fx) = SSA(VlookupSS(SS), 2)
    QcfA(n, Gx) = DiscA(VlookupDisc(Disc), 3)
    
    If SS = "" Then
        QcfA(n, Cx) = "TBD"
        QcfA(n, Dx) = "TBD"
        QcfA(n, Ex) = "TBD"
        QcfA(n, Fx) = "TBD"
    End If

    ' QCF Status Treatment
    Select Case QCFStatus
        Case Is = "Inspection Step", "Open RFI"
            QcfA(n, Hx) = "Pending"
            QCFStatusA(n, 1) = ""
        Case Is <> "Inspection Step", "Open RFI"
            QcfA(n, Hx) = "Done"
    End Select
Next n

' Copy the modified arrays back into their ranges
WS_Mast_QCF.Range("A1:H50000").Value = QcfA
WS_Mast_QCF.Range("N1:N50000").Value = QCFStatusA
```

This uses a function that I wrote to simplify building the dictionaries that replace  the VLookup calls:

```
Function BuildVLookupDictionary(ValuesArray() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    'ignore duplicate key errors
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(ValuesArray, 1)
        dict.Add ValuesArray(r, 1), r
    Next r
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set BuildVLookupDictionary = dict
End Function
```

Comment: OMG!!!! I will give it a try, but I'm honest I don't get a clue of what this all means. I learnt VBA by myself, on the job. This is way more complex than what I can understand. I will le you know for sure. Thanks. Many thanks.

Comment: @nikau It basically follows the logic of your original code.  I just 1) copied the ranges into arrays before the loop.  2) Made Dictionaries to imitate how you use VLookup (but faster). 3) inside the loop read and write to the arrays instead of the ranges.  4) After the loop, copy the modified arrays back into the ranges that they came from.  This all may seem like a lot of extra steps but it works because reading/writing array cells is 100x faster than reading/writing Excel cells, and bulk copying range-values to/from arrays is not much faster than doing it one cell at a time.

Comment: And the `Scripting.Dictionay` is like a VBA `Collection`, only better.

Comment: One thing to know: the array references are reversed from range references.  So `.Range("A" & n)` becomes `array(n, Ax)` in my code.  That's annoying, but it's just how it works (Excel is odd because it puts the column reference first, whereas most languages' arrays have the row index first).

Comment: I'm testing. Seems way more faster as you promised. I'm benchmarking right now. There's probably few mistakes in your code as the results are not as expected, but arrays are really what I should work on as I have many loops like that in my run . Sad I don't  have the time to redo all. Thanks for this. I will post the benchmark result of course

Comment: I'm not sure of my benchmarking. Seems that sometimes my loop freeze and wait for me to click anywhere to continue... However, your code is always < 30s, when mine is over 1 minute,( when it doesn't freeze). Thanks for the tips and advices.

Comment: Many thanks. This simple loop duration jump from 6 minutes to 1 minutes. I still trying to figure out how this work.

Comment: The only issue, it's that the Vlookup only return "empty" values.

Comment: Find where the problem probably is  "For r = 1 To UBound(DiscA, 1)" in the function. DisA is not applicable for all Vllokup

Comment: @nikau Yep, that should’ve been UBound(ValuesArray, 1).

Comment: Yes I found the solution. And I've also use your code for other loops. Work perfectly fine. I'm now trying to make it work with a xlookup function, instead of vlookup.