# Speeding up my code for string text replacement

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

As an addition to my previous question which I got a response to, and which helped me to complete the project in super speedy time, I now have a similar project, for which the original code already works and works well, but, I have two columns which contain as follows:

Column K - Names of ws's and servers and their IP addresses comma delimited
Column L - Just the ip addresses

In each batch of names and IP's, or just IP's, there are ranges that I am not interested in having appear in the final output for various reasons.

Sadly, I can't give real examples of the strings, but the following are samplings of what you may find:

K - Mike [10.6.3.4], Mike1 [10.2.3.4], Mike3 [10.165.75.3]....... (differing amount of such
L - 10.6.3.4, 10.2.3.4, 10.165.75.3............

The IP's in L are the same as those in K, but not necessarily in the same order.

This does not matter.

I wrote the following sub which runs through all the rows in the excel ws, and reads in the strings and then writes out the same strings without the ranges I do not want (you will see that those are 10.6. and 192.168.

As you will see, I wrote a loop for the first string in a row, and then a second loop for the second string in the same row based on the column, I clean off training commas (I don't know how to set the new array which will hold the "clean" strings the the end length so I get a bit of extra commas which I have to clean) and then I go to the next row until the end.

It works fine.

I just have a feeling that it can be done faster, and cleaner, as well as in one loop and not two, as well as maybe not getting the extra commas that need cleanup.

I'd appreciate any comments or fixes anyone may have.

Again, it works fine, but it feels "unclean" if you understand what I mean.

```
'Sub to remove unwanted IP ranges from both columns
Sub CleanNamesIPsfromList()

    Const Col_Names = "J"
    Const Col_IPs = "K"
    Const ROW_NamesIPs = 5 'First line of Names and IP's

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim arHoldNames() As String, arHoldIPs() As String
    Dim arPutNames() As String, arPutIPs() As String
    Dim strHoldNames As String, strHoldIPs As String
    Dim txt106 As String, txt192168 As String
    Dim rn As Long, rhn As Long, ri As Long, rhi As Long, lastrowN As Long, lastrowI As Long, i As Long
    
    txt106 = "10.6."
    txt192168 = "192.168."

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        Set wsMain = .Sheets("Main")
    End With

    With wsMain
        lastrowN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_Names).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrowI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_IPs).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastrowN < ROW_NamesIPs Or lastrowI < ROW_NamesIPs Then
            MsgBox "No text found in Columns " & Col_Names & " " & Col_IPs, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Run through whole ws row by row in both columns
        For i = ROW_NamesIPs To lastrowN
            rhn = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            strHoldNames = .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldNames = Split(strHoldNames, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutNames(0 To UBound(arHoldNames))
            For rn = 0 To UBound(arHoldNames)
                If InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment rn to next array cell and move on
                    rn = rn + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutNames(rhn) = arHoldNames(rn)
                    rhn = rhn + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value = Join(arPutNames, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(.Cells(i, Col_Names).Value, 1) = ","
                .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value = Left(.Cells(i, Col_Names).Value, Len(.Cells(i, Col_Names).Value) - 1)
            Wend

            rhi = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            strHoldIPs = .Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldIPs = Split(strHoldIPs, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutIPs(0 To UBound(arHoldIPs))
            For ri = 0 To UBound(arHoldIPs)
                If InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment ri to next array cell and move on
                    ri = ri + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutIPs(rhi) = arHoldIPs(ri)
                    rhi = rhi + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            .Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value = Join(arPutIPs, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(.Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value, 1) = ","
                .Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value = Left(.Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value, Len(.Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value) - 1)
            Wend
        
        Next 'Move to next row and repeat untill end
    End With 'End main

End Sub
```

New CODE

Ok, based on the reading all the data into the array, I wrote this section of code (borrowing of course from betters).

```
    Dim Lastcell As Range
    Set LastCell = .Range("K5:L5").End(xlDown)
    
    'capture all of the data at once with a range-array copy
    Dim arHoldAllNames As String, ArHoldAllIPs As String
    arHoldAllNames = .Range("K5", LastCell).Value
    ArHoldAllIPs = .Range("L5", LastCell).Value

    for i = 0 to UBound(arHoldAllNames, 1)
        'Code for Names
    Next
    for i = 0 to UBound(ArHoldAllIPs, 1)
        'Code for IPs
    Next

    temp = 0
    For i = 5 To LastCell
        .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value = arHoldAllNames(temp)
        .Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value = ArHoldAllIPs(temp)
        i = i + 1
        temp = temp + 1
    Next
```

Is this what you all meant ?

Also, I saw I can read a range of data into an array, which definetaly speeds things up.

So that would be this bit of code:

```
    arHoldAllNames = .Range("K5", LastCell).Value
    arHoldAllIPs = .Range("L5", LastCell).Value
```

Can I then reverse that and do:

```
.Range("K5", LastCell).Value = arHoldAllNames 
.Range("L5", LastCell).Value = arHoldAllIPs
```

And have all the cells in the ws propogates with what is in the arrays ?

Or do I still need to do the For loop:

```
    temp = 0
    For i = 5 To LastCell
        .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value = arHoldAllNames(temp)
        .Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value = ArHoldAllIPs(temp)
        i = i + 1
        temp = temp + 1
    Next
```

Comment: A very large improvement would be to take all the values from the sheet into an array, do all changes within the array and then put the array back into the sheet. I've seen my projects have a 90% reduction in run-time from that change.

Comment: My sheets can have anything from 7000 to 20000 rows. Not that an array could not hold that. So you are saying, read all the data from both columns into two separate arrays and then do the work on those arrays instead of the ws ?

Comment: Specifically, use range-array copying.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164840/how-can-i-open-this-vba-workbook-faster/19167804#19167804.  Such as `dim data as variant: data = Range("A1:D10000"): data(r,c) = ... : Range("A1:D10000") = data`.  So, copy all of the values (that you need) at once into a variant array, change the values in the array, then copy them all at once back into the spreadsheet cells.  It's *much* faster..

Comment: This one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130319/simple-loop-but-through-50-000-lines/68132284#68132284) may be easier to read.  Specifically look at the first and last few lines of code.

Comment: I edited the last bit of my question to show what I wrote. I would appreciate knowing of it will do the job (logically, I will obviously test myself), and whether I can reverse the flow of reading a range into an array, into propagating a range from an array in one line, or if I still need the For loop.

Comment: ok, I saw that you actually answered everything already @RBarryYoung, and also made the changes to the code. I am going to give that a shot in a bit and will let you know if it does the deal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it with Range-Array copying:

```
'Sub to remove unwanted IP ranges from both columns
Sub CleanNamesIPsfromList()

    Const Col_Names = "J"
    Const Col_IPs = "K"
    Const ROW_NamesIPs = 5 'First line of Names and IP's

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim arHoldNames() As String, arHoldIPs() As String
    Dim arPutNames() As String, arPutIPs() As String
    Dim strHoldNames As String, strHoldIPs As String
    Dim txt106 As String, txt192168 As String
    Dim rn As Long, rhn As Long, ri As Long, rhi As Long, lastrowN As Long, lastrowI As Long, i As Long
    
    txt106 = "10.6."
    txt192168 = "192.168."

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        Set wsMain = .Sheets("Main")
    End With
    
    Dim NamCel As Variant
    Dim IpCal As Variant

    With wsMain
        lastrowN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_Names).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrowI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_IPs).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastrowN < ROW_NamesIPs Or lastrowI < ROW_NamesIPs Then
            MsgBox "No text found in Columns " & Col_Names & " " & Col_IPs, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Range-array copy the data into VBA
        NamCel = .Range(Col_Names & "1:" & Col_Names & lastrowN)
        IpCel = .Range(Col_IPs & "1:" & Col_IPs & lastrowI)

        'Run through whole ws row by row in both columns
        For i = ROW_NamesIPs To lastrowN
            rhn = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            'strHoldNames = .Cells(i, Col_Names).Value
            strHoldNames = NamCel(i, 1)
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldNames = Split(strHoldNames, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutNames(0 To UBound(arHoldNames))
            For rn = 0 To UBound(arHoldNames)
                If InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment rn to next array cell and move on
                    rn = rn + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutNames(rhn) = arHoldNames(rn)
                    rhn = rhn + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            '.Cells(i, Col_Names).Value = Join(arPutNames, ",")
            NamCel(i, 1) = Join(arPutNames, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(NamCel(i, 1), 1) = ","
                NamCel(i, 1) = Left(NamCel(i, 1), Len(NamCel(i, 1)) - 1)
            Wend

            rhi = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            strHoldIPs = IpCel(i, 1)
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldIPs = Split(strHoldIPs, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutIPs(0 To UBound(arHoldIPs))
            For ri = 0 To UBound(arHoldIPs)
                If InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment ri to next array cell and move on
                    ri = ri + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutIPs(rhi) = arHoldIPs(ri)
                    rhi = rhi + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            IpCel(i, 1) = Join(arPutIPs, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(.Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value, 1) = ","
                IpCel(i, 1) = Left(IpCel(i, 1), Len(IpCel(i, 1)) - 1)
            Wend
        
        Next 'Move to next row and repeat untill end
    
        ' Range-array copy the data back out to Excel
        .Range(Col_Names & "1:" & Col_Names & lastrowN) = NamCel
        .Range(Col_IPs & "1:" & Col_IPs & lastrowI) = IpCel
    End With 'End main

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, It works Wayyyyyyyyyy faster. There was a "subscript out of range" which I fixed and damn, it's fast :) I am going to answer my question and place the new code in there. I learnt something new and will impliment it in future codings I do. Thank you very much @RBarryYoung. Marked your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

With the ideas given, and the code help RBarryYoung wrote, and a simple change to get rid of the subscript out of range error I was getting when reading the string from the main array into the small work array, the code is as follows.

```
'Sub to remove unwanted IP ranges from both columns
Sub CleanNamesIPsfromList()

    Const Col_Names = "J"
    Const Col_IPs = "K"
    Const StrtRow = 5 'First line of Names and IP's

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim arHoldNames() As String, arHoldIPs() As String
    Dim arPutNames() As String, arPutIPs() As String
    Dim strHoldNames As String, strHoldIPs As String
    Dim txt106 As String, txt192168 As String
    Dim rn As Long, rhn As Long, ri As Long, rhi As Long, lastrowN As Long, lastrowI As Long, i As Long, RlLstRw As Long
    Dim NamCel As Variant, IpCal As Variant
    
    txt106 = "10.6."
    txt192168 = "192.168."

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        Set wsMain = .Sheets("Main")
    End With
    
    With wsMain
        lastrowN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_Names).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrowI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col_IPs).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastrowN < StrtRow Or lastrowI < StrtRow Then
            MsgBox "No text found in Columns " & Col_Names & " " & Col_IPs, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Range-array copy the data into VBA
        NamCel = .Range(Col_Names & StrtRow & ":" & Col_Names & lastrowN)
        IpCel = .Range(Col_IPs & StrtRow & ":" & Col_IPs & lastrowI)

        'Run through whole ws row by row in both columns
        RlLstRw = lastrowN - 4
        For i = 1 To RlLstRw
            rhn = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            'strHoldNames = NamCel(i, 1)
            strHoldNames = NamCel(i, 1)
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldNames = Split(strHoldNames, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutNames(0 To UBound(arHoldNames))
            For rn = 0 To UBound(arHoldNames)
                If InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldNames(rn), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment rn to next array cell and move on
                    rn = rn + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutNames(rhn) = arHoldNames(rn)
                    rhn = rhn + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            NamCel(i, 1) = Join(arPutNames, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(NamCel(i, 1), 1) = ","
                NamCel(i, 1) = Left(NamCel(i, 1), Len(NamCel(i, 1)) - 1)
            Wend

            rhi = 0
            'Load list of names into string holder
            strHoldIPs = IpCel(i, 1)
            'Split the string into the holding array based on the comma
            arHoldIPs = Split(strHoldIPs, ",")
            'Loop through the array to find those names not containg unwanted data
            ReDim arPutIPs(0 To UBound(arHoldIPs))
            For ri = 0 To UBound(arHoldIPs)
                If InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt106, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, arHoldIPs(ri), txt192168, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'If it contains unwanted string, increment ri to next array cell and move on
                    ri = ri + 1
                Else
                    'I want this string so put in new array holder and increment array counter
                    arPutIPs(rhi) = arHoldIPs(ri)
                    rhi = rhi + 1
                End If
            Next 'Loop through array holding origional string
            'I have what I want, so put it back in relevant cell in ws
            IpCel(i, 1) = Join(arPutIPs, ",")
            'Remove all trailing commas
            While Right(.Cells(i, Col_IPs).Value, 1) = ","
                IpCel(i, 1) = Left(IpCel(i, 1), Len(IpCel(i, 1)) - 1)
            Wend
        
        Next 'Move to next row and repeat untill end
    
        ' Range-array copy the data back out to Excel
        .Range(Col_Names & StrtRow & ":" & Col_Names & lastrowN) = NamCel
        .Range(Col_IPs & StrtRow & ":" & Col_IPs & lastrowI) = IpCel
    End With 'End main

End Sub
```

Thank you everyone. Great help as always.

The script runs on my laptop about 120 times faster with 8,323 rows (2 and a bit seconds to complete it all). So on my ws it will be even faster.